# Is it ever okay to catch a generic exception in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess

I was just reading through [this article from Real Python](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/) about the evils of catching **generic exceptions**.

I'm working on a large-ish program in Python at the moment. This program **spawns some subprocesses** (using `Popen`) and then calls some other code over and over again. Being a large program, it has the potential to throw **a variety of classes of exception**, many of which I haven't even thought of yet. This is a problem because it means that **the subprocesses aren't killed properly**.

I want to do something like this:

```py
while keep_going_signal():
    try:
        do_the_thing()
    except Exception as e:
        kill_subprocesses()
        raise Exception(e)
```

However, given the dire warnings about catching generic exceptions in the aforementioned article, I'm a bit nervous about doing so.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Work with the errors you do know about and expect. and catch them explicitly. If other errors occur you can then update your code and test cases to ensure its caught and handled appropiatly.

Comment: It's OK in this case IMO. The exception police won't come and arrest you...

Comment: Although you are catching all exceptions, you aren't *supressing* or *ignoring* them. You ensure your processes are stopped, then re-raise the exception in case any one *else* can do something to recover. This is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a catch-all exception handler as long as it does not catch more exceptions than the action in the handler is meant to handle. The action in your exception handler is meant to perform a cleanup for all errors, so it justifies a catch-all exception handler.

That said, to re-raise an exception in an exception handler, you should instead use the `raise` statement without passing to it a new `Exception` object in order to preserve the call stack in the associated traceback object for debugging purposes:

```
try:
    do_the_thing()
except Exception:
    kill_subprocesses()
    raise
```

Answer (score 2):

Catching an exception means that you are prepared to handle *certain kinds of problems* which may occur and that you *have a plan* for what to do when that happens. That should *usually* be as narrow as possible, so you're really only handling the specific problems you're prepared for and for which you have a specific remedy.

Now, if your code is very broad, then it also makes sense to have a broad error handling. Say you're writing a web framework like Flask or Tornado. You'll be making calls into user supplied code, over which you have zero influence and which may raise *any* kind of error. But just because the user code raised an error, you don't want that to affect the web server. So you'd always encapsulate any and all calls into unknown user code with the broadest possible exception handler, because your primary goal is to keep the server running, regardless of what issues the user code may have.

So, yes, it's perfectly fine to have a generic exception handler in the right circumstances.

Comment: That was a great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about cleaning the process but not catching everything you could `try... finally`:

```
while keep_going_signal():
    try:
        do_the_thing()
    except SomePrettyLikelySpecificException e:
        handle_it()
    finally:
        if process_is_still_running():
            kill_subprocesses()
```

You'd have to supply `process_is_still_running()` yourself, of course.

There may be some exception(al) situations which take the whole of the runtime down with them, in which case your subprocesses are probably beyond saving.

(Edit: this example catches the predictable exception types which we believe we can handle. Others have pointed out the significance and merits of this and of re-throwing ones we can't handle.)

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html